# Two ways to new ArrayList in java

Tags: java

Generally, I can new an ArrayList in this way(if element is String):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

However, I find a new way to do it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

It seems I can save much code by the second way if the element in the list is complex type.

Any difference between those?

Comment: For future reference it might be useful to you to read through Java release notes to see what language changes have been done in each release; then you don't have to be surprised (google: "java 7 changes", "java 8 changes", etc.). And speaking from experience, the amount of code you save is actually not *that* great ;) Its a convenience, not a game changer.

Comment: I agree with Gimby, read the release notes of Java8. There is some more stuff such as Lambda expressions supported in Java8, which was not available before Java8. Also, they made significant changes to security stuff for Java8. It caused many of the applications to fail in large systems, so many vendors just didnt support Java 8, but it was worth it. Now project Jigsaw is in development and coming(confirm this) in Java9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type inference was added in JDK 1.7, the second style.

> It seems I can save much code by the second way if the element in the list is complex type.

You it automacially infers if you are using 1.7 or +, which means the ArrayList gets the type of It's declared List.

Called as Diamond operator and purpose of the diamond operator is to simplify instantiation of generic classes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the second version isn't supported before Java (compiler) version `1.7`.

Therefore if you want your source code to be compilable with JDK 1.6, it can't use the new syntax.

Comment: I think it's called **automatic type inference** if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is an example of [Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) (<> is informally called "diamond operator") which was introduced in Java 7.

You're encouraged to use it on Java 7 or Later for brevity of code.